# Lua Corona SDK Conflicting Event Listeners

Tags: lua, coronasdk, event-listener

**[SOLVED]** Thanks for looking, but I figured it out. I needed to un-nest the `return true` statements in some of my if conditions.

I have just started learning Lua this week, and I have started to program a 2D side-scroller game using Corona SDK. In this game, the player's character is moved by pressing buttons displayed on the screen much like a virtual game pad. These buttons work perfectly, however, the problem is that I have a

```
Runtime:addEventListener("tap", onScreenTap)
```

event listener that then calls the shoot() function to fire a projectile from the player whenever a tap is registered. This results in a projectile firing every time I lift the touch from one of the movement buttons.

Is there any way I can stop the shoot function from calling when I finish touching one of the movement keys? I have tried

```
display.getCurrentStage:setFocus()
```

and also putting

```
return true
```

at the end of the movement functions but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this basics in every touch function you have.. Or just this for all touch events. Combining touch events in a single function may solve your problem.

```
function inBounds( event )
    local bounds = event.target.contentBounds
    if event.x > bounds.xMin and event.x < bounds.xMax and event.y > bounds.yMin and event.y  < bounds.yMax then
        return true
    end
    return false
end 


function touchHandler( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
        -- Do stuff here --
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(event.target)
        event.target.isFocus=true
    elseif event.target.isFocus == true then
        if event.phase == "moved" then
            if inBounds( event ) then
                -- Do stuff here --
            else
                -- Do stuff here --
                display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(nil)
                event.target.isFocus=false
            end
        elseif event.phase == "ended" then
            -- Do stuff here --
            display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(nil)
            event.target.isFocus=false
        end
    end
    return true
end
```

By the way, if you try to use this in Runtime, it will throw and error. You can add an event listener to background or just put some control mechanisnms like

```
if event.target then
-- blah blah
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dogancan, I can see how this syntax can be very helpful. However, I solved the problem I was having.